# How to check if the User input does not include any number while typing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, user-input

I have an input from user for his first name

I wanna immediate check the values he enter if it's less than 4 I will create a div that holds him the error

also I wanna check if the input has any numbers I will create a div also to tell him that he shouldn't enter a digit in his name

so this is my Html Code first

```
<div> <label> <span> First Name:  </span>  <input type="text" name="FirstName" id = "myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter your First Name..." /> </label> </div>
```

and this is my java Script Function

```
function is_number(input) {
  if(input === '')
      return false;
  let regex = new RegExp(/[^0-9]/, 'g');
  return (input.match(regex) === null);
}


function myFunction() {  
    const x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
    if (x.length < 4){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You Enterd less Than 4 Numbers"
  }
  else if(is_number(x)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "First Name Should Not Have Digits in it"
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: > If it's less than 4
If it is less than 4 chars of length, did you mean?
And more: you can use `regex = new Regex(/[^0-9]/, "g")`, but form basic JS types, form performance (and comprehension) reasons, it's better to use something like `regex = /[^0-9]/g` directly, as the new will be instancing an object, instead of a simple type.

Comment: is exactly what I meant ,,, I wanna create a function that 1- Check that the name field is not empty and at least 4 characters 2-that name field does not include any digit (0-9) while the user is writing his name and if the user Enterd a number error massage will appear and if he removes the digits the error maseage disappears

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sanitize the input:

```
function isValid(input) {
  let regex = /[A-Z]/i;
  if(!regex.test(input)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "First name should not have digits in it"
  }

  if(input.length < 4) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You entered less than 4 characters"
  }
}
```

The `/[A-Z]/` pattern only matches alphabet characters and the `i` flag ignores the characters case.
The pattern matches both the empty strings and numbers. It also matches characters like `'` when followed preced by a alphabet character, so names like "O'brien" are fine.